# How to change ToolTipDescription of "Delete Button" using ribbons in Dynamics 2016?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, microsoft-dynamics

I am trying to change the TOolTipDescription of DELETE button in Microsoft Dynamics through ribbonsDiff.xml. It is not letting me change and throwing the error "cannot edit property until element is customized". I have customised it by defining it in ribbonDiff.xml file. But it is not changing the behavior of the DELETE button. Any way to change the ToolTipDescription of DELETE button ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get yourself a wonderful tool called the [Ribbon Workbench](http://www.develop1.net/public/page/Ribbon-Workbench-for-Dynamics-CRM-2011.aspx).  Then see [Change the text or image of a standard button](https://ribbonworkbench.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/138809-change-the-text-or-image-of-a-standard-button).  Here's a high-level summary:

1. Install Ribbon Workbench in your org
2. Create a solution that contains just the entity you are trying to modify
3. Open Ribbon Workbench and select your solution
4. Near the top right corner of the screen, select the ribbon type that has the delete button you are trying to modify.
5. In the ribbon that appears, right-click the Delete button and choose Customise Button.
6. Modify the ToolTipDescription field down below.
7. Click publish.